# Problem installing the tour

Tags: networking, tor

I'm new to Linux and I had a problem installing Tor, so when I give the command `journalctl -exft Tor` to the terminal, it doesn't go up to 10%. molaei.org/tor-ubuntu/ I went ahead. Thank you for your help.

```
~/Desktop$ journalctl -exft Tor
```

ژوئن 13

```
10:35:45 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: We compiled with OpenSSL 30000020: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 and we are running with OpenSSL 30000020: 3.0.2. These two versions should be binary compatible.
ژوئن 13 10:35:45 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Tor 0.4.6.10 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 3.0.2, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.5, Libzstd 1.4.8 and Glibc 2.35 as libc.
ژوئن 13 10:35:45 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://support.torproject.org/faq/staying-anonymous/
ژوئن 13 10:35:45 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
ژوئن 13 10:35:45 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
ژوئن 13 10:35:45 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
ژوئن 13 10:35:45 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9050
ژوئن 13 10:35:45 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
ژوئن 13 10:35:45 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
ژوئن 13 10:35:45 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
ژوئن 13 10:35:45 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Starting with guard context "default"
ژوئن 13 10:35:45 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Signaled readiness to systemd
ژوئن 13 10:35:46 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Opening Socks listener on /run/tor/socks
ژوئن 13 10:35:46 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on /run/tor/socks
ژوئن 13 10:35:46 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Opening Control listener on /run/tor/control
ژوئن 13 10:35:46 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Opened Control listener connection (ready) on /run/tor/control
ژوئن 13 10:35:46 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
ژوئن 13 10:35:46 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay
ژوئن 13 10:41:54 arian-ariana Tor[4294]: Interrupt: exiting cleanly.
ژوئن 13 10:41:54 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: We compiled with OpenSSL 30000020: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 and we are running with OpenSSL 30000020: 3.0.2. These two versions should be binary compatible.
ژوئن 13 10:41:54 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Tor 0.4.6.10 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 3.0.2, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.5, Libzstd 1.4.8 and Glibc 2.35 as libc.
ژوئن 13 10:41:54 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://support.torproject.org/faq/staying-anonymous/
ژوئن 13 10:41:54 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
ژوئن 13 10:41:54 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
ژوئن 13 10:41:54 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
ژوئن 13 10:41:54 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9050
ژوئن 13 10:41:54 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
ژوئن 13 10:41:54 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
ژوئن 13 10:41:54 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
ژوئن 13 10:41:54 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Starting with guard context "default"
ژوئن 13 10:41:54 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Signaled readiness to systemd
ژوئن 13 10:41:55 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Opening Socks listener on /run/tor/socks
ژوئن 13 10:41:55 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on /run/tor/socks
ژوئن 13 10:41:55 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Opening Control listener on /run/tor/control
ژوئن 13 10:41:55 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Opened Control listener connection (ready) on /run/tor/control
ژوئن 13 10:41:55 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
ژوئن 13 10:41:56 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay
ژوئن 13 10:49:15 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 7BE683E65D48141321C5ED92F075C55364AC7123 at 193.23.244.244:443)
ژوئن 13 10:49:15 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 10 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 10:49:15 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 10:50:41 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (CONNECTRESET; CONNECTRESET; count 11; recommendation warn; host 568B6913AE5123EDBA304909A569AFE8F9E73C4C at 192.42.253.215:9001)
ژوئن 13 10:50:41 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 11 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 10:50:41 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  11 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 10:50:56 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 12; recommendation warn; host BD6A829255CB08E66FBE7D3748363586E46B3810 at 171.25.193.9:80)
ژوئن 13 10:50:56 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 12 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 10:50:56 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  12 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 10:51:12 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 13; recommendation warn; host AC66FFA4AB35A59EBBF5BF4C70008BF24D8A7A5C at 195.154.164.243:443)
ژوئن 13 10:51:12 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 13 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 10:51:12 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  13 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 10:51:16 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 14; recommendation warn; host CF6D0AAFB385BE71B8E111FC5CFF4B47923733BC at 154.35.175.225:443)
ژوئن 13 10:51:16 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 14 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 10:51:16 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  14 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 10:51:57 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (CONNECTRESET; CONNECTRESET; count 15; recommendation warn; host B845B963455133613C9694FD46D0432945A00871 at 107.189.8.230:9001)
ژوئن 13 10:51:57 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 15 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 10:51:57 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  15 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 10:52:47 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (CONNECTRESET; CONNECTRESET; count 16; recommendation warn; host 139C86C4C9BC94E89BAF79B15EBFDF9396DD5BB0 at 199.249.230.156:443)
ژوئن 13 10:52:47 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 16 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 10:52:47 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  16 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 10:52:56 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 17; recommendation warn; host 24E2F139121D4394C54B5BCC368B3B411857C413 at 204.13.164.118:443)
ژوئن 13 10:52:56 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 17 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 10:52:56 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  17 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 10:53:16 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 18; recommendation warn; host 1B9C26C1DAB190EAD3EBADB70914E0949ADC2588 at 185.25.50.199:9000)
ژوئن 13 10:53:16 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 18 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 10:53:16 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  18 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 10:53:27 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (CONNECTRESET; CONNECTRESET; count 19; recommendation warn; host 4141FDA554F56E9E24DA41153B5C1A756EE43249 at 107.173.159.48:9001)
ژوئن 13 10:53:27 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 19 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 10:53:27 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  19 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 10:54:57 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 20; recommendation warn; host F8D27B163B9247B232A2EEE68DD8B698695C28DE at 78.47.18.110:80)
ژوئن 13 10:54:57 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 20 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 10:54:57 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  20 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 10:55:49 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (CONNECTRESET; CONNECTRESET; count 21; recommendation warn; host 2D8A907F61CAED48170963B76BE4FB0ED33E5E88 at 80.98.81.157:9001)
ژوئن 13 10:55:49 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 21 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 10:55:49 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  21 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 10:56:01 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 22; recommendation warn; host C0DAAAE5EE461BBE13945FE4B52F32ABDC6BC376 at 51.15.246.170:443)
ژوئن 13 10:56:01 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 22 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 10:56:01 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  22 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 10:57:44 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 23; recommendation warn; host F2044413DAC2E02E3D6BCF4735A19BCA1DE97281 at 131.188.40.189:443)
ژوئن 13 10:57:44 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 23 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 10:57:44 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  23 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 10:59:47 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 24; recommendation warn; host 7EA6EAD6FD83083C538F44038BBFA077587DD755 at 45.66.33.45:443)
ژوئن 13 10:59:47 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 24 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 10:59:47 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  24 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 11:04:31 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 25; recommendation warn; host 847B1F850344D7876491A54892F904934E4EB85D at 86.59.21.38:443)
ژوئن 13 11:04:31 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 25 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 11:04:31 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  25 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 11:06:00 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 26; recommendation warn; host 79B207AD51842FA215D956B9307B3D01CD347368 at 37.252.187.129:9001)
ژوئن 13 11:06:00 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 26 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 11:06:00 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  26 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 11:11:33 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (DONE; DONE; count 27; recommendation warn; host 9695DFC35FFEB861329B9F1AB04C46397020CE31 at 128.31.0.39:9101)
ژوئن 13 11:11:33 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 27 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 11:11:33 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  27 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 11:12:46 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay. (CONNECTRESET; CONNECTRESET; count 28; recommendation warn; host 85D3D0C3D4699AFA897FE9DD9270BAACBBE3E3F1 at 185.112.146.188:9001)
ژوئن 13 11:12:46 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: 28 connections have failed:
ژوئن 13 11:12:46 arian-ariana Tor[5245]:  28 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3/TLS write client hello in HANDSHAKE
ژوئن 13 11:17:27 arian-ariana Tor[5245]: Interrupt: exiting cleanly.
```

Comment: I'd suggest a network connectivity problem. Can you `ping  -c3` each of the IP addresses in the log entries? Or `traceroute` them? Is your National Internet Policy Anti-Tor?

Comment: yes is Anti-tor